# Xerces-C++ DOM node line/column number location

Tags: c++, xml, dom, xerces

I'm writing a custom XML validator using Xerces-C++. My current approach loads the document into a DOM, and then checks are performed on it. What I need is a way to access the line/column number of a node in the DOM. I've been reading the API docs and googling, but I'm coming up short. Is it possible to somehow retrieve this kind of information about the nodes?

Implementing the [`XMLValidator`](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/apiDocs-3/classXMLValidator.html) interface looks like it would probably provide me with that kind of info, but it would require completely rewriting the intended validation architecture. Frankly, an `XMLValidator` approach seems ugly and monolithic. I have a different and *much* simpler validation system in mind (one that is also easily parallelizable) and everything works; all I need is the line/column number info of the nodes. The Qt DOM implementation that I've used before (and which I can't use now) [provides this information up front](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qdomnode.html#lineNumber), so I can't see why Xerces is making things difficult.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**A possible solution can be found [here](http://markmail.org/message/fofympr5oendfnxx).**

Comment: The link is down...